# Right ideal $eS$ in a simple semigroup $S$ without zero, with idempotent $e$ and minimal left ideal $L$ is a minimal right ideal of $S$.

Tags: ideals, semigroups

Suppose that $S$ is like in the title, a simple semigroup without zero, with a minimal left ideal $L$ and idempotent $e$. We can always assume that $L = Se$.

I've already proved few facts about $S$. I know that $S$ is a sum of it's minimal left ideals, that $Se$ is a left group, and that $H_e = eSe$ is a group. This was also a part of the exercise.

How do I prove that $eS$ is a minimal right ideal? If possible, I'd like a hint before a full solution. It's an exercise from a subsection '$0$-minimal ideals and $0$-simple semigroups' if that helps.

Suppose that $J$ is a right ideal of $S$ such that $JS\subseteq J\subseteq eS$. If $e\in J$, then $J = eS$ is obvious. I want to draw a contradiction in the case when $e\notin J$, so far no luck.

Note that $Sa = L$ [$aS = L$] for any $a\in L$ if $L$ is left [right] minimal ideal.

Comment: Did you already proved that $e$ is a minimal idempotent?

Comment: If trusting [this article](https://zenodo.org/record/1059032/files/september2013-6.pdf), minimal idempotent would seem to be an idempotent such that $Se$, $eS$ are minimal left and right ideals and $H_e = eSe$ is a maximal subgroup of $S$. This is much stronger than what I want to prove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will use that $eSe$ is a group.

Note that $eS$ being minimal right ideal of $S$ is equivalent to $eS$ being right simple. This means that every principal right ideal of $eS$  is equal to $eS$, i. e. $\forall_{s\in S} eseS = eS$.

Because $eSe$ is a group, for any $s\in S$ there exists $r\in S$ such that $(ese)(ere) = e$. Hence $$esereS = eS \subseteq eseS \implies eS = eseS.$$ Hence $eS$ is right simple, and so a minimal right ideal.